# Javascript prototype: possível mudar valor do objeto de referência?

Tags: javascript, objetos, protótipo

EDIT: Normalmente é no final, mas a pergunta foi mal formulada e decidi trocar por esse exemplo que é bem melhor. Segue o exemplo de uma função que não faz nada como método de Array:

```
Array.prototype.nada = function () {
    var In = this;
    var Out = new Array();
    for (var i=0; In.length>0; i++) { Out.push(In.pop()); }
    In = Out;   
    console.log("Resultado interno: ");
    console.log(Out);   
}
```

Para testar...

```
function testeNada() {
    var Nada = ["Eu","Você","Nós"];
    Nada.nada();
    console.log("Resultado de Nada: ");
    console.log(Nada);
}
```

No Safari, o resultado interno de Out é a mesma Array do início (Nada) e o resultado do teste de Nada é uma Array vazia!

No caso das prototypes métodos pré-existentes, funciona assim:

```
var UmaArray = new Array();
UmaArray.push("umValor"); // UmaArray já é ["umValor"]
```

Pela lógica, eu faria assim:

```
Array.prototype.empurre = function(valor){
 Arr = this;
 Arr.push(valor);
 this = Arr; // Aqui dá erro ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference
}
var UmaArray = new Array();
UmaArray.empurre("umValor"); // Sonho de ver UmaArray ser ["umValor"]
```

Ou seja, não é possível modificar a si mesmo.

Conforme já mencionado abaixo nos comentários, tirando this = Arr o método funciona. Então refaço a pergunta: existe alguma forma de realmente mudar o objeto de referência o apenas aplicando métodos nele mesmo?

Comment: Não entendi porque você quer atribuir um valor a `this`, ainda mais que no seu exemplo esse valor é ele mesmo... Se tirar essa linha seu código já funciona como você quer.

Comment: De fato, acho que não fui feliz nessa pergunta. Vou retirar. Obrigado.

Comment: Refiz toda a pergunta com um exemplo mais simples e direto.

Comment: Mesmo assim ainda não entendi o que você está tentando fazer! Seu novo exemplo faz exatamente o que eu esperava dele. Tem algo que não está claro pra você, mas ainda nao descobri bem o que é.

Comment: Na primera vez tentei explicar porque cheguei nesse ponto. Eu aproveito funções para criar métodos, só que no fim não dá para simplesmente pegar o resultado e "enfiar" dentro do objeto. O código terá que ser modificada conforme explica o picossi abaixo. Então eu modifiquei a pergunta e deixei apenas o conceito para outros que procurarem com esse tipo de dúvida. Eu tenho vários métodos que terei que modificar para que o objeto apresente o resultado no final, faz parte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem duas maneiras de fazer isso:

Se você usar o `this` diretamente vai estar alterando o obj de ref.

```
Array.prototype.empurre = function(valor){
    this.push(valor);
};
var UmaArray = new Array();
UmaArray.empurre("umValor");
```

A segunda maneira é parecida com a implementação do rotate

```
Array.prototype.empurre = function(valor){
    var push = Array.prototype.push;
    push.apply(this, [valor]);
};
var UmaArray = new Array();
UmaArray.empurre("umValor");
```

Comment: Refiz a pergunta que não estava clara. Acho que sua resposta significa que a única forma é aplicar sempre em cima de "this", certo?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo :D

Answer (score 1):

A razão pela qual o primeiro exemplo retorna `[]` é porque `In` é um ponteiro do `this` e a cada iteração do loop estás a fazer `In.pop()`.

Para alterar a própria array podes fazer assim:

```js
Array.prototype.inverter = function() {
    for (let i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        this[i] = this[i].split('').reverse().join('');
    }
}
var array = ["Eu", "Você", "Nós"];
array.inverter();
console.log("Resultado de Nada: ");
console.log(array); // ["uE", "êcoV", "sóN"]
```

Basicamente, métodos que mudem o `this` fazem o que pediste. Todos os métodos de *Array* que mudam o objeto original (como `.pop()`, `.shift()`, etc) mudam o `this` dentro dessa função adicionada ao *prototype*.